# Android layout xml using view class="com.example.MyView" vs com.example.MyView

Tags: android, android-layout

There are two ways to declare view control in Android layout xml

First - more commonly found and used through [Android Layout documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

```
<com.example.MyView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and second one

```
<view class="com.example.MyView" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

What is the difference between the two, if there is any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If custom view is defined as *nested static class* it has to be declared using the `class` atribute, if it is *top-level class* it can be declared either way - with the XML element name or with the `class` attribute.

As documented in [Android Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

---

`MyEditText` is nested static class in `NoteEditor` class:

```
<view
  class="com.android.notepad.NoteEditor$MyEditText" 
  id="@+id/note"
  .../>
```

---

`MyEditText` is a top-level class:

```
<com.android.notepad.MyEditText
  id="@+id/note"
  ... />
```

or

```
<view
  class="com.android.notepad.MyEditText" 
  id="@+id/note"
  .../>
```